# Firebird TIME SQL format displayed properly in TMaskEdit with mask: '!90:00;1;_'

Tags: delphi, firebird

I have Firebird table with field 'ABC' of `Time` type. I use `TMaskedEdit` to populate it with mask: `!90:00;1;_`

It works fine when populating the field with values but does not work properly when displaying values from the field.

I use:

```
editABC.Text := DateTimeToStr(fieldbyname('ABC').AsDateTime);
```

The problem I get is that time like for example: `14:48` is displayed as `14:00`

Question: how can I display value of field of type `Time` properly in `TMaskedEdit` properly?

Comment: Use `FormatDateTime('hh:nn', FieldByName('ABC').AsDateTime)` for converting your time field value. Or just switch to `TDateTimePicker` control.